# Invalid INT key in kafka topic after creating kTable

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have topic "users" created by command:

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic users --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact
```

In Redpanda data on topic looks good.
Then I create kTable:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS_TABLE (LOCATION_ID INT, NAME STRING PRIMARY KEY) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='users', KEY_FORMAT='KAFKA', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

And queryable kTable:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATIONS_DATA AS SELECT LOCATION_ID, COLLECT_LIST(NAME) AS NAMES FROM USERS_TABLE GROUP BY LOCATION_ID EMIT CHANGES;
```

After creating tables on topic "LOCATIONS_DATA" there are invalid keys in Redpanda (looks like '?' or key is empty):

[image: invalid keys]

In ksqlDBCLI while selecting table or printing topic keys are ok.

When "LOCATION_ID" is STRING or VARCHAR keys in LOCATIONS_DATA topic are correct. However, I would like to keep the LOCATION_ID as INT.

Answer (score 0):

Integers aren't encoded at UTF8 bytes that can be displayed in a GUI. It's a UI bug in the Redpanda console, not with ksqlDB